# redirect www to no www

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, apache, bitnami

i use aws ec2 bitnami wordpress built a webiste. but i face one issue.
for installing SSL, I Changed .conf document. now I faced one problem.
i can open the domain abc.com (for example only) but can not open www.abc.com.when i want to open www..abc.com , it redirect the address to http://abc.comhttps//www.abc.com/.
May i now how to solve it?
[image: https://snipboard.io/3F7IqY.jpg]

Comment: can you post your `.conf` file?

Comment: just add `http(s)://` before `www..abc.com`.

Comment: change home_url, site_url values inside wp_options table.

Comment: the problem now is when i click www.example.com. it returns the link below http://example.comhttps//www.example.com/.but if i click example.com, the site can open.  so i don't know where i can edit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

Please follow these steps to force the redirection to HTTPS in our stack:

- Add the following lines in the default Apache virtual host configuration file at /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf, inside the default VirtualHost directive, so that it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

- Restart Apache to apply the changes.

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

You can find more information about this redirection in [our documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/force-https-apache/)

Comment: thanks, we really tried the above code. it is the same as the code shown i posted . only no-www domain works. if type www.example.com. it returns wrong url. example.comhttp//www.example.com. i checked one day now but have no idea

Comment: Please check the comment in the other answer you posted. You added several RewriteCond and RewriteRule entries. Those ones are modifying the URL and making that weird redirection. What you can do is to remove all the "Rewrite" lines and then follow our documentation from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

I not sure how edit .conf here, can I add the conf code here for checking?

```html
# Default Virtual Host configuration.

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfVersion>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^panasonicservomotor.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://panasonicservomotor.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny                          
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Default SSL Virtual Host configuration.

<IfModule !ssl_module>
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
</IfModule>

Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH !RC4"
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^panasonicservomotor.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://panasonicservomotor.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
  SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key"
            
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny                          
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
        
  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Bitnami applications that uses virtual host configuration
Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf"
```

Comment: Hi, you added several RewriteRules without adding the proper flags and that's why you are redirected to the correct URL. Please check the answer I posted this morning and ensure your .conf file looks like the code I provided.